# MS-Access database searching algorithm in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, ms-access, asp-classic

**The Problem**

Given a database of 10,000 items, I would like to go about doing the following:

1. search by any of the columns
2. match results by a variable number of letters at the beginning of the result
3. print out duplicate results
4. the rest of the information for that entry is appended to the search

Consider the table in ms-access (omitting the primary key)

```
Header1|Header2|Header3
 apple   rotten  green
 apple   fresh   yellow
 pear    fresh   blue
 orange  rotten  pink
```

Given the following search by *Header1*; apple, pear

I would receive the result:

```
 apple, rotten, green
 apple, fresh, yellow
 pear, fresh, blue
```

Similarly, given the search by *Header1*; pear, orange, pear

I would receive the result:

```
 pear, fresh, blue
 orange, rotten, pink
 pear, fresh, blue
```

**What I'm doing**

My approach is to store the header you are searching for and an array containing the elements that you searched for. I retrieve the WHOLE database (it's large so this wouldn't be the preferred method) and order it by the header chosen, and also sort the input that the user gave me (both lists in ascending order).

By using simple comparisons (strComp = 0, -1, 1) I increment counter variables for the respective list. This, however, does not account for the cases where the user inputs a duplicate AND the table has a duplicate result. It only accounts for one or the other of those cases.

My solution to that issue would be to "roll" up and down when we find a result to check for nearby results as well, but that seems horrible, nor does it account for fuzzy string matching.

Any recommendations? The solution should somehow stay O(n) if possible given that the user input can (and will) be > 100,000

Comment: Things that come to mind: 1) Precisely define what you mean by *"match using fuzzy string"*. 2) Is the database properly normalized (3NF or higher)? If not what's the rationale? 3) Did you define any indexes? 4) Does it have to be an Access DB? There are more capable DB engines available, for example with full text search support. 5) Describe the use case from the user's perspective. 6) Why would "pear, fresh, blue" be two times in the second search result?

Comment: @Tomalak 1) Ideally It would involve Levenshtein, however I'm going to go on a limb and say that would not allow for O(n) so instead a threshold number of letters at the beginning of the word to match. 2) No sadly, the data is given to me and is all relevant. 3) No, could you elaborate? 4) Yes... Believe me i'd love to use ANYTHING else 5) Filling out excel forms with partial information on an entry (ex: all names, need extra info) 6) to keep the users' entered data consistent to what they entered

Comment: 1) I see. Yes, Levenshtein would increase the workload considerably. 2) Is your database one single flat table? 3) Indexes order column data and allow for O(log(n)) search time on that column (for exact string or start-of-string searches). In exchange they increase database size.

Comment: So if the search is `apple, pear, apple`, you would return 5 rows? A search like this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Tomalak 2) Yep 3) No i don't have indexes, the table is pretty much exactly like the example i described

Comment: @Andre yes it would return 5 rows, I know how that seems redundant and entirely useless but it's a requirement to keep the initial input list in 'order' - as in it has to have the same logic flow as was input regardless of redundant searches

Comment: 2) Well, that's less than ideal... 3) I suggest you start with defining indexes on any column that you are likely to search in. This should boost any query with `[ColumnName] = 'input'` or `[ColumnName] LIKE 'input*'`

Comment: @Tomalak so rather than pulling ALL the rows and omitting the ones that i dont need, you suggest I pull for each input? The reason I didnt do that is that with 100,000 inputs, it would practically be DDOS'ing the server, since it only allows one open query at a time. Alongside that, it would be impossible to request a WHERE clause with 100,000 names

Comment: Well... A database is meant to process SQL queries and return only matching records, as as efficiently as possible. A "WHERE clause with 100,000 names" is not in the domain of things that make any sense in the context of databases. So either you are misunderstanding how databases work, or am misunderstanding what use case you are trying to model. I can't help but suspect that you are trying to solve a rather poorly defined problem with the worst-possible tools.

Comment: (cc: @Tomalak ) - So are you saying that for a table of ~10,000 rows you are looking to process a search of the form "Header_n; term_1, term_2, ..." where there can be in excess of 100,000 terms? I'm having trouble imagining that, partly due to your completely inadequate response to Tomalak's request for a description of the use-case.

Comment: @GordThompson That's exactly what i'm saying. And that's where the issue of dealing with duplicates both in the database and inputs comes in. That's where my algorithm falls entirely short. The use-case: imagine I have a list of first names for every student in a school. I'd like to augment that list with their Email Address and Address. My list, however, may contain duplicate first names (not everyone has a unique first name in reality) and so for each first name, all similar rows containing that name must be returned WITH the extra info requested.

Comment: @GordThompson however, there's also the case where someone decided to look up the same name by accident n separate times throughout the input. In that case, the input may exceed the database rows

Comment: Hmm, okay, but if (1) excess search terms are the result of "someone [deciding] to look up the same name by accident n separate times" and (2) the duplicate query terms will return the same rows each time, then why do you care? It sounds to me like it's just unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @GordThompson I understand that, but that's just one of the requirements, it's not my call

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you construct a dynamic `UNION ALL` query, with one `SELECT` statement for each search.

`UNION ALL` returns all rows, including duplicates.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Header1 LIKE 'apple*'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Header1 LIKE 'pear*'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Header1 LIKE 'apple*'
```

With indexes on the columns that are searched, this should be reasonably fast.

Comment: But I'm not seeing how this could be a good solution for 100,000 fruit searches at once. you'd be union-ing 100,000 separate queries

Comment: Oh *that* was what you meant by "100,000 inputs". Hm. You could try doing it in chunks of e.g. 100 selects per query, and appending the results, but as Tomalak wrote, this seems not really like a job for a database.

Comment: Yes, that's why i'm pulling ALL the information in the database and only omitting the results that aren't pertinent to the input given by comparing the recordset and the array of inputs. This way, amortized runtime doesn't change. I was wondering if there were steps i'm missing either in the query or in the asp-side that would speed up the process.

Comment: The way to speed up this approach is by building a search-friendly data structure out ouf your raw data. How this might look like depends. Dictionaries lend themselves to this task. It's a matter of slicing your data effectively and putting it into an organized hierarchy that matches the expexted query format. Cached for reuse, a search tree over 10,000 or 100,000 data points is not that much, really.

Comment: @Tomalak although building a dictionary would omit duplicates entirely (unless i add some sort of unique identifier), i think that's probably the best I can do. Thank you!

Comment: That's why I said "sliced and organized cleverly". A hierarchy of dictionaries (one for every column and substring length) that themselves contain arrays of row indexes would be conceivable. A manually built tree of custom VBS objects would be conceivable. A hybrid approach that indexes all keywords to length N and then uses a loop to filter the match candidates  would work. Think about normalizing your strings to ASCII, too. It really depends.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you so much, sorry I didn't express myself well initially. Feel free to make that an answer if you'd like, i'll accept it.

Comment: How about that: You implement something that works for your situation, clean up your question a bit, and when you have a proof-of concept solution you share the code in an answer of your own, for the benefit of others who might be looking for it. That would be a hell of a lot more useful than me posting a bunch of vague suggestions into an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98254/discussion-between-cristiand-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 0):

My solution;

First: Store the data (comma delimited) from the database in a dictionary as value with the key being the value for the searched header. If an entry already exists, simply append the new data to the previous data with a bar delimiter.

Second: loop through the list of inputs and match them (with a simple first N characters comparison - if necessary) with the items in the dictionary. If you found a match, get the value and split by delimiters accordingly.

I believe this stays an O(n) solution so long as the first N characters comparison is not used.